# Массив через цикл

Tags: java

как можно через один цикл for печатать несколько массивов ... заранее спасибо

Comment: int x[] = new int[10];
 int y[] = new int[6];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно использовать цикл с двумя переменными счётчиками и придумать условие в этом цикле. Например вот так:

```
 public void printArrays() {
    int[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int[] y = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < x.length || j < y.length; i++, j++) {
        if (j < y.length) {
            System.out.println("массив x: " + x[i] + " массив B: " + y[j]);
        } else {
            System.out.println("массив x: " + x[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Вот ещё один вариант без дополнительных переменных и который не зависит от того какой массив длиннее, а какой короче. `length` - длинна массива, метод `Math.max` возвращает максимальное из двух значений.

```
  int[] x = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int[] y = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
    for (int i = 0; i < Math.max(x.length, y.length); i++) {
        if (i < x.length && i < y.length) {
            System.out.println("массив А: " + x[i] + " массив y: " + y[i]);
        } else if (i > y.length) {
            System.out.println("массви A: " + x[i]);
        } else if (i > x.length) {
            System.out.println("массив B: " + y[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: А как можно филтровать пара из цифер и считать их количество ????